# How to Assert DataTable in NUnit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I've written a `Unit Test` based on `NUnit framework` and I'd like to know how should I Assert `DataTable` that returned from my methods.

Currently, I've done that like below:

```
[Test]
public void GetTableColumns_WhenCalled_ShouldReturnTableColumnList()
{
    // Act
    DataTable dataTable = _sut.GetTableColumns(Statics.SystemUsersTableName);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(dataTable, "DataTable is empty");

}
```

Is it best practice to Assert DataTable data's with `Assert.IsNotNull` method?

Comment: What behavior is it that you are actually trying to assert? This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It is best practice when you want assert that DataTable is not null.

Comment: @Nkosi I want to check the returned DataTable has some row and make sure that my method works fine.

Comment: @AhmadPayan then you need to also inspect the table and confirm its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Test]
public void GetTableColumns_WhenCalled_ShouldReturnTableColumnList()
{
    // Act
    var dt= _sut.GetTableColumns(Statics.SystemUsersTableName);

    // Assert
    Assert.That(!dt.HasRow());

}

public static bool HasRow(this DataTable dt)
{
 return dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0;
}
```